# How do I get Spring Security OpenID Connect to work from behind a corporate firewall?

Tags: java, spring-security, openid-connect

I'm trying to get OIDC working from behind a corporate firewall, and I'm running into some issues.

I am trying to use the Google as my OpenID provider.  I have configured an OAuth 2.0 Client ID in Google with type "Web Application".

I have updated my application.yaml and added the following properties:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        google:
          client-id: <client-id from google>
          client-secret: <client-secret from google>
```

I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class with the following configure() method (shamelessly copied from Baeldung):

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        Set<String> googleScopes = new HashSet<>();
        googleScopes.add(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        googleScopes.add(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

        OidcUserService googleUserService = new OidcUserService();
        googleUserService.setAccessibleScopes(googleScopes);

        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauthLogin -> oauthLogin
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .oidcUserService(googleUserService)
                );
    }
```

When I attempt view the application in a browser, everything initially looks good.  I get redirected to google to authenticate, and then google redirects back to my application.  However it all goes south when the application attempts to exchange the authorization code for a access token.

I get the following error:

```
[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token 
Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token": Software caused 
connection abort: recv failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection 
abort: recv failed
```

Ok, looks like an issue with the corporate firewall.  Cool, no problem I'll just use a RestTemplateCustomizer.  So I declare the following beans:

```
    @Bean
    HttpHost proxyHost(@Value("${http.proxyHost}") String proxyHost) {
        log.debug("Setting proxy host to: '{}'", proxyHost);
        return HttpHost.create(proxyHost);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner proxyRoutePlanner(HttpHost proxyHost) {
        return new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxyHost);
    }

    @Bean
    HttpClient httpClient(DefaultProxyRoutePlanner proxyRoutePlanner) {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(proxyRoutePlanner).build();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient) {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    RestTemplateCustomizer restTemplateCustomizer(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory) {
        RestTemplateCustomizer restTemplateCustomizer = (RestTemplate template)->{
            log.debug("Returning a customized rest template.");
            template.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);
        };
        return restTemplateCustomizer;
    }
```

This failed to fix the problem. After some debugging, I realized that the DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient is creating its restOperations by calling `new RestTemplate()` rather than using RestTemplateBuilder, so all of my work to create a RestTemplateCustomizer is for nothing.

So I updated my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
public class OidcSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    public OidcSecurityConfigurer(@Autowired RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        Set<String> googleScopes = new HashSet<>();
        googleScopes.add(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        googleScopes.add(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

        OidcUserService googleUserService = new OidcUserService();
        googleUserService.setAccessibleScopes(googleScopes);

        http
                .authorizeRequests(
                        authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauthLogin -> oauthLogin
                        .tokenEndpoint(teCustomizer->{
                            DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient client = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
                            client.setRestOperations(this.restTemplateBuilder.build());
                            teCustomizer.accessTokenResponseClient(client);
                        })
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .oidcUserService(googleUserService)
                );

    }

}
```

This got a little further.  Now it was getting connected to google, but it wasn't able to read the response due to a NullPointerException on line 80 in DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:80) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.java:57) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.getResponse(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:170) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:195) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
```

Looking at the code, it seems that the token isn't being decoded properly because I didn't add the right messageConverters to the RestTemplate.  So updated the RestTemplateCustomizer declaration as follows:

```
    @Bean
    RestTemplateCustomizer restTemplateCustomizer(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory) {
        RestTemplateCustomizer restTemplateCustomizer = (RestTemplate template)->{
            log.debug("Returning a customized rest template.");
            template.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);
            template.setMessageConverters(
                    Arrays.asList(
                        new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
                        new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter()
                    )
            );
            template.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());
        };
        return restTemplateCustomizer;
    }
```

Now the access token is being decoded correctly, but the JWT user token is failing. WTH?  So I looked at the class NimbusJwtDecoder and it *also* is calling `new RestTemplate()`.  So I apparently need to figure out how to change the RestTemplate being used by the NimbusJwtDecoder similar to what I did for DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient.

At this point I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree.  This seems like *so* much work just get the built-in OAuth2 support working.  It almost seems like it would be easier to just handle the all the OAuth2 handshake stuff manually rather than using what's built into spring-security.  The kicker is that this is primarily an issue that will only occur during development.  For a production deployment of the app they can easily open the firewall to allow the application to make outgoing connections to the OpenID provider.

I would appreciate any guidance anyone could give.

Thanks,
Dave